# How to make RestAssured.filters() Thread Safe?

Tags: java, multithreading, rest-assured

I am using RestAssured for my API Automation and I am using ExtentReports to log the request and response. It works fine when I run in a single thread. But when I run in multiple threads, it doesn't seem to be thread-safe. Logs of one thread are getting clogged in the other. Below is my TestList Class:

TestListClass.Java

```
public class TestListener implements ITestListener, ISuiteListener {

  String line = new String(new char[150]).replace('\0', '-');

  ExtentReportHelper report;
  ExtentReports extent;
  ExtentTest test;
  private StringWriter requestWriter;
  private StringWriter responseWriter;
  private PrintStream printRequestStream;
  private PrintStream printResponseStream;

  @Override
  public void onTestStart(ITestResult result) {

    log.info("\n");
    log.info(line);
    log.info(StringUtils
        .center("Test case :-->  \"" + result.getName() + "\"  <--: about to start...", 130));
    log.info(line + "\n\n");
    test = extent.createTest(result.getName());
    apiLogsReport();
  }

  private void apiLogsReport() {
    requestWriter = new StringWriter();
    responseWriter = new StringWriter();
    printRequestStream = new PrintStream(new WriterOutputStream(requestWriter,"UTF-8"));
    printResponseStream = new PrintStream(new WriterOutputStream(responseWriter,"UTF-8"));
    RequestLoggingFilter requestLoggingFilter = new RequestLoggingFilter(printRequestStream);
    ResponseLoggingFilter responseLoggingFilter = new ResponseLoggingFilter(printResponseStream);
    RestAssured.filters(requestLoggingFilter, responseLoggingFilter);
  }

  @Override
  public void onTestSuccess(ITestResult itr) {
    log.info(line);
    log.info(StringUtils.center(String.format("|%30s|", itr.getTestClass())
        + String.format("|%20s|", itr.getName()) + String.format("|%10S|", "passed"), 120));
    log.info(line + "\n");
    test.log(Status.PASS,
        MarkupHelper.createLabel(itr.getName() + " PASSED ", ExtentColor.GREEN));
    printRequestStream.flush();
    printResponseStream.flush();
    report.logRequestResponse(test, requestWriter, responseWriter);
  }

  @Override
  public void onTestFailure(ITestResult itr) {
    log.info(line);
    log.info(StringUtils.center(String.format("|%30s|", itr.getTestClass())
        + String.format("|%20s|", itr.getName()) + String.format("|%10S|", "failed"), 120));
    log.info(line + "\n");
    test.log(Status.FAIL, MarkupHelper.createLabel(itr.getName(), ExtentColor.RED));
    test.fail(itr.getThrowable());
    printRequestStream.flush();
    printResponseStream.flush();
    report.logRequestResponse(test, requestWriter, responseWriter);
  }

  @Override
  public void onTestSkipped(ITestResult itr) {
    log.info(line);
    log.info(StringUtils.center(String.format("|%30s|", itr.getTestClass())
        + String.format("|%20s|", itr.getName()) + String.format("|%10S|", "skipped"), 120));
    log.info(line + "\n");
    test.log(Status.SKIP,
        MarkupHelper.createLabel(itr.getName() + " SKIPPED ", ExtentColor.ORANGE));
    test.skip(itr.getThrowable());
    printRequestStream.flush();
    printResponseStream.flush();
    report.logRequestResponse(test, requestWriter, responseWriter);
  }

@Override
  public void onStart(ITestContext context) {
    report = new ExtentReportHelper();
    extent = report.initReport(testNgHelper);
  }
```

logRequestResponse method()

```
public void logRequestResponse(ExtentTest test, StringWriter requestWriter, StringWriter responseWriter) {
        String[] requests = requestWriter.toString().split("Request method:");
        String[] responses = responseWriter.toString().split("HTTP/1.1");
        for (int i = 1; i < requests.length; i++) {
            test.log(Status.INFO, "<pre>Request: " + requests[i] + "\nResponse: " + responses[i] + "</pre>");
        }
    }
```

Am I doing something wrong? Or doesn't RestAssured filters support multi-threaded execution? Please help me out if there is any other way to do so if it is not thread-safe.

Comment: Did you try log text to extent report without `RestAssured.filters` ? Does it work correct or not?

Comment: I can do that and I guess that would work. But it doesn't make sense to write the logging to extent report in every @Test method as there are so many test cases.

Comment: I guess the problem comes from where you created the `PrintStream` and assigned to these kinds of filters. Besides RA maitains the internal variable `filters = new LinkedList<Filter>();`. When run multithread, many filters created --> duplicate log, however, they need share the I/O to print ---> hold and delayed, maybe print log to wrong place. It's just my thoughts, not sure.